# is this "obs" the abbreviation of observers or objects in R language?

Tags: r

I am a newbie in R language learning when I create a data.frame the Global Environment shows n obs. of n variables.
is this "obs"  the abbreviation of observers or objects?
ty

Comment: Please, could you provide a code? Here how to write a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Assuming you are talking about the RStudio Environment panel, "obs" refers to the number of rows in your data.frame.

Comment: It's an abbreviation of "observations" (the technical term in statistics).

Comment: @MrFlick also ty .yes obs in the RStudio Environment panel's  Global Environmen！

Answer (score 1):

Here, I've loaded `mtcars`:

[image: mtcars in RStudio's Environment browser]

The `32 obs. of 11 variables` refers to that the data.frame contains **32 observations** (i.e. rows in the data.frame). In this dataset, this corresponds to a specific car model.

Each car model is described with **11 variables** - these are shown as columns in the data.frame.

If you at first load the dataset with the command `data(mtcars)`, you will notice RStudio instead writes `<promise>`. This is because the data is not loaded into your environment, but you made R promise that the data is available. It will be loaded once you start using it. This is referred to as "lazyloading" - you make R aware that you have an intent to use it, but R only loads it when you actually need it.

Comment: ty very much for your reply  :) nice